# How similar can a {service in location} landing page be, before it cannibalizes surrounding areas?

Tags: local-seo, landing-page

I have a website which targets multiple "*service* in *location*" keywords.

I have noticed in some SERPs I am appearing twice in the top 5. I normally wouldn't mind but I have a feeling I might be cannibalizing my own pages.

How close can 2 locations be before cannibalization starts to happen?

Comment: Google considers pages for different locations that are too similar to be search engine spam.   They call it [doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en).   It isn't a matter of cannibalization, it is a matter of getting your entire site penalized if you have pages that are very similar but differ in their keyword targeting.  See: [White Hat / Black Hat SEO in 2018: Are Location Pages Considered Doorway Pages?](https://esultants.com/blog/2018/01/16/are-location-pages-considered-doorway-pages)